# An archiver that supports compression, encryption, retain permissions, and fast at retrieving file

Tags: linux, gzip, tar, 7zip, rar

I have a directory with a big amount of data and I want to archive it.  I need

1. Supports compression.  The compression can saves a lot of disk space;
2. Supports password encryption.  The data is sensitive so I want it not readable if the disk is stolen;
3. Retain *NIX permission;
4. Fast to retrieve a file, meaning if I just need to get a small file from it, it should be fast and won't read the whole archive.

All well-known archivers in my mind don't meet all the above criterion:

- TAR: it is not compressed, no password encryption;
- TAR.GZ / TAR.BZ2 / TAR.7Z: if you just need one file from it, you need to uncompress the tar.gz file until the tar gets to the file you need;
- 7Z / RAR: not retain permissions;
- ZIP: not encrypted and not retain permission

Anyone has suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Try looking into Info-ZIP, which is supposed to retain permissions (both UNIX and NTFS).

http://www.info-zip.org/

Seems like it hasn't been updated in a while though, and I don't have personal experience with it, so not sure if it meets your needs.

Comment: Info-ZIP does all of the above, except it has encryption by name only.  The original zip encryption was quite poor and allegedly breakable, and unfortunately that's what Info-ZIP implements.

Comment: Right, the encryption is weak.  I would like to have better protection.